# ave releted to my project

Tags: asp.net, database

I want to fetch data from two table buut i m realy confused.

just i want recent two users in my site but problem is there that two users releted information stored in other table .

I also used join query to fetch that data but proper result not get .

Comment: I think you will need to add some more details and examples before people can help you. Post the table structures and the join query that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the correct results when you run your query in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?  Make sure you can isolate where your problem is.

If the query returns the correct results when you run it in SSMS, then post up your code and we can help you find the problem.

If the query isn't returning your desired results post the table structure and the query and we can help you with that.